# Using physics to move a object along a track/rail

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm hoping to simulate the movement of a train along a fixed path. The path itself is representable by a CGPath.

So far, I've found SKPhysicsJointSliding, which seems close, but appears to only work along a fixed axis, and since my path has curves that seems like a deal breaker.

I know I could use a series of SKActions to accomplish the movement, but in my case it's far preferable to have the physics engine handle the movement for me.

My question is basically whether or not this is something the SpriteKit physics engine can accommodate via something I've missed in the documentation (or if I'm somehow misunderstanding the sliding joint)?

Answer (score 0):

Why is "physics" more preferable? Once you're on rails, you aren't really utilizing the physics engine. If you're looking for semi-realistic y-axis yaw as it rumbles down the track, try doing a random rotation about that axis.

You could also try utilizing the `SKNode.physicsBody` as well. According to Apple's docs, your `SKNode` doesn't participate in physics simulations until you attach one.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483117-physicsbody

Giving it mass and other physical properties could simulate slowing down, speeding up, etc.

Otherwise, you will have to do a lot of complicated math to apply physical forces in the direction you want the train to go.